# How to maintain reference to class variables in class functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to store references to the class variables in javascript and performa a generic function. For example,

```
export class RecruitingFilterStore extends BaseStore {
    constructor(rootStore:RootStore) {
        super(rootStore);
    }

    @observable
    businessStrategies: number[] = [];

    @observable
    educations: number[] = [];

    @observable
    experiences: boolean[] = [];

    @observable
    certificates: number[] = [];

    @action
    toggleFilter(key: string, value:any) {
        const keyMap = {
            businessStrategies: this.businessStrategies,
            educations: this.educations,
            experiences: this.experiences,
            certificates: this.certificates,
        } as any;

        let prevObs = keyMap[key];

        const idx = prevObs.indexOf(value);

        if (idx > -1) {
            prevObs.splice(idx, 1);
        }else {
            prevObs = [
                ...prevObs,
                value,
            ]
        }

        keyMap[key] = prevObs;
        console.log(keyMap[key] === this.certificates) // this is false
    }
}
```

the `toggleFilter` cannot update the class variables because the reference to the original class variable is lost. How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Use bind? https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/javascript-tips-apply-vs-call-vs-bind-d738a9e8b4e1

Comment: That expression is also not guaranteed to be true as two different arrays are never ===. Insufficient information is provided on invocation context and state arguing that the === _should_ be true, which would only indicate that a new array is being assigned/compared (idx == -1) or not (idx > -1)..

Comment: `prevObs` management is redundant, just work directly with `this[key]`. (e.g. `if (idx > -1) this[key].splice(idx, 1); else this[key].push(value)`)

Comment: If you are trying to call ```toggleFilter``` without correct context, you could try to add ```@action.bound``` decorator instead of ```@action```